# Facing issue while converting java code to objective c code using j2objc

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, j2objc, j2objc-gradle

I am trying to convert some of the java files to objective c classes. But i am facing some issue here. kindly check the image below.

Command i have given:
[Click here to see the command i have given](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8633.png)

Error i got: [Click here to check the error i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15Vep.png)

All the java files are present in the source path but y am i getting this error.

Comment: please don't post images of text, and please don't post links.  Include the text in your question so that it can be found by searches.

Comment: Your path has a space in between and hence it doesn't seem to run. Give the path in quotes "". Let me know if it doesn't work still.